# Flutter FlutterFire installation

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cli

I'm struggling with installing flutterfire on my Android Studio.
I've successfully logged in with my account to Firebase, using `firebase-tools-instant-win`.
I've successfully installed flutterfire in Android Studio, using the command line:

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

It automatically added `flutterfire_cli: ^0.2.7` to dependencies.
But now when I try to run the command line `flutterfire configure` it shows me this message:

> ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.
> google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it.

I've also checked the env table and added the required PATH for firebase, but I still get the same error message.

To not forget to mention, there are no firebase tools like (.firebase, firebase.json) in my project.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `firebase-cli` to use flutterfire configure use this command:

`npm install -g firebase-tools`

ensure that you have installed `node` installed

Here is the documentation you have to follow in case you don't have node.js or if you need any information : Firebase CLI documentation

Comment: I ran this command one more time. As you can see: https://i.imgur.com/fTu34fD.png
But I still get the same error when using the command ``flutterfire configure``

Answer (score 0):

you have to install firebase-cli to use flutterfire configure use this command:

npm install -g firebase-tools

ensure that you have installed node installed

Here is the documentation you have to follow in case you don't have node.js or if you need any information : Firebase CLI documentation